# memtable_flush_writer significance and uses

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

Can anyone tell about memtable_flush_writers use case and significance. And in what situation we should tune from default value? I have already read the datastax docs but not clear the actual uses and benefits.

Comment: is there a reason you are looking to tune it? It shouldnt impact read/write performance as its non blocking (in 2.1+). Unless theres a GC impact from memtables getting too large I would recommend to leave it as is.

Comment: Now a days we are facing some performance and memory issue on our cassandra cluster so looking to tune it. we are also using JBOD configuration on our cluster.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `memtable_cleanup_threshold` is computed as: 1 / ( `memtable_flush_writers` + 1)

There is some guidance in the YAML about how to set this value, as Mehul pointed out.  Contrary to that, I would *never* set that to number of cores, regardless of whether or not you're using SSDs.

The problems come when the `memtable_flush_writers` is set too high, your node can become overwhelmed with small flushes that trigger compaction.  This has the unfortunate side effect of causing your commitlog to fill up, and eventually get to a point where it cannot keep up with the flush frequency.

If that happens, you can force a flush manually using `nodetool flush`.  But if you see your commitlog filling your disk, lowering your `memtable_flush_writers` is a good thing to try.

NoteL: As with all "tuning" like changes with Cassandra, I'd make incremental changes over time, as opposed to a drastic change.  Just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

**memtable_cleanup_threshold** : When the total amount of memory used by all non-flushing memtables exceeds this ratio, Cassandra flushes the largest memtable to disk.

**memtable_flush_writers** : THis defines the number of memtable flush writer threads. The threads will write parallel on disk (sstables). But changing this parameter is suggest in case solid-state drive (SSD)  is used.
   Note :  If your data directories are backed by SSDs, increase this setting to the number of cores.

I hope this solves your query.